# How to debug huge data collections in Intellij

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

In the application, I have huge data set in various collection container such as List, Map, Set, etc. For example:-

```
static List<Employee> employeeList = Arrays.asList(
        new Employee("Tom Jones", 45),
        new Employee("Harry Major", 25),
        new Employee("Ethan Hardy", 65),
        new Employee("Nancy Smith", 22),
        new Employee("Deborah Sprightly", 29),
        new Employee("Billy Kid", 22),
        new Employee("George King", 44),
        new Employee("Annie Barrey", 19));
```

Here are only a few items in the list hardcoded. But if I have more than 10 thousands of item in the list. How can I verify an Employee named  "George King" is exist in this list? I know how to do it by code. But will it be possible to quickly verify this in the Intellij debugger? My assumption there should be some way. Please let me know how can do it without stepping and iterate all the values one by one.

Comment: You could stop in the spot you want to check using breakpoint - and then use Evaluate to check - with just simple contains.

Comment: As mentioned above, you can write code and evaluate it at runtime. In Eclipse you can also create 'Expressions'. It takes a Java command and it executes it at every step. If you put a breakpoint after the collection is filled, it will execute for example a contains command and shows you the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to set a conditional breakpoint, with the condition being `contains(...)` sort of thing.

Answer (score -1):

you can try setting a breakpoint in this line

```
static List<Employee> employeeList = Arrays.asList(
```

and check the content in the list in the debugger window like in the image below.

[image]

Thanks, I hope this answers your question.